# Sum column from inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you sum a column from an inner join?

I have got this far but the results are not correct, for example.

```
SELECT DISTINCT it.CODE, pl.UNITS
FROM ITEMDETAILS it inner join plant pl ON it.CODE = pl.CODE 
WHERE it.LOCNUMBER = '3434';
```

This give me this result which is correct

```
CODE    UNITS
GE-ARH  2
GE-ARV  2
GE-EC   0.5
GE-JB   0.5
GE-JT   0.5
GE-VL2  2
GE-VL4  2
```

I then want to sum all the UNITS into a TOTAL, but when I execute the below query it gives me the wrong calculation?  Can anyone show me the error of my ways?

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(pl.UNITS) as TotalUnits 
FROM PLANT pl inner join ITEMDETAILS it on pl.CODE = it.CODE
WHERE it.LOCNUMBER = '3434';

TotalUnits
972
```

The answer obviously should be 9.5, I presume it is calculating against the whole column and not taking the where clause into consideration, but not sure why?

Thanks for your help as always.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using, in case it is relevant?

Comment: Your query is returning 972 because it is not summing the distinct values that you are returning in your original query. You are instead pulling the distinct sum. Adrian's or Dumitrescu Bogdan solution below will fix it.

Comment: Cheers JChao, Dumitrescu gave me the correct answer.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: Is it the correct answer? In your question you do not provide data for both source tables, just an interim result. I feel you could avoid distinct altogether (and probably should) - and knowing which dbms is used is needed also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
select sum(units) 
from
(
  SELECT DISTINCT it.CODE, pl.UNITS
  FROM ITEMDETAILS it inner join plant pl ON it.CODE = pl.CODE 
  WHERE it.LOCNUMBER = '3434'
) un
```

Or depending on the sql version

```
;with un as (
  SELECT DISTINCT it.CODE, pl.UNITS
  FROM ITEMDETAILS it inner join plant pl ON it.CODE = pl.CODE 
  WHERE it.LOCNUMBER = '3434'
)
select sum(units)
from un
```

Comment: Thanks Dumitrescu, the first query was perfect.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Take Care! using distinct could give you misleading (incorrect) results I don't know that it will - but it can (depends on the data)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this

```
SELECT SUM(UNITS) AS TOTAL_UNITS
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT it.CODE, pl.UNITS
    FROM ITEMDETAILS it inner join plant pl ON it.CODE = pl.CODE 
    WHERE it.LOCNUMBER = '3434'
) X
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me at the `distinct` keyword. I missed it. I deleted my post since it didn't provide anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of joining a "detail table" to another is to facilitate the where condition "WHERE it.LOCNUMBER = '3434'". take that away and there is no purpose to the join.

Could it be that this join is the sole cause of the unwanted repetition (aka "duplicates") and hence a different method could be followed. e.g.

```
SELECT
      pl.CODE
    , pl.UNITS
FROM plant pl
WHERE pl.CODE IN (
            SELECT
                  it.CODE
            FROM ITEMDETAILS it
            WHERE it.LOCNUMBER = '3434'
      )
;
```

and

```
SELECT
      SUM(pl.UNITS)
FROM plant pl
WHERE pl.CODE IN (
            SELECT
                  it.CODE
            FROM ITEMDETAILS it
            WHERE it.LOCNUMBER = '3434'
      )
;
```

Instead of IN() one could use EXISTS () with a correlation in the subquery.

---

Note if the dbms supports sum() over() then that could produce the overall total as a column.